# ¿Cómo insertar varios objetos en un campo tipo json?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo la siguiente tabla (muestro el campo que me interesa)

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.tours__tours (
    [...]
    pricing json[] NULL,
    [...]
);
```

Como pueden ver e campo  `pricing` es de tipo json[], y al querer insertar un registro en la tabla, me da un error de `malformed array literal`. Estoy tradando de insertar pricing con la siguiente cadena:

```sql
INSERT INTO public.tours__tours (pricing)
VALUES('{{"id":"1","prop":"value"},{"id":"2","prop":"value",}}')
```

Ya intenté también encerrando el objeto como `[{{},{}}]`, o tratando de hacer cast con `::json` pero el error me sale siempre

Comment: ¿Y que error tienes? mirándolo rápido no parece un json válido. Prueba esto:`INSERT INTO public.tours__tours (pricing)
VALUES('[{"id":"1","prop":"value"},{"id":"2","prop":"value"}]')`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho tampo, esto ya lo había intentado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

intenta con el constructor `ARRAY`

```
INSERT INTO public.tours__tours (pricing)
VALUES(ARRAY ['{"id":"1","prop":"value"}'::json,'{"id":"2","prop":"value"}'::json])
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! No había encontrado esta opción. Funciona bien.